# How to read files inside directory in parallel using spark

Tags: apache-spark

How to read files inside directory in parallel using spark

I sc.textfile but it reads each file sequentially

Comment: This is a low quality question. Please refer to the official guide !

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the difference between `sc.textFile` and `sc.WholeTextFiles`
`sc.textFile` reads all the file inside the given directory and creates a partition as number of file. If there are 5 files then it creates 5 partitions.

`sc.WholeTextFiles` read all the file inside given directory and creates a PairRDD with file path as a key and file content as a value.The partitions depends upon the number of executors

Comment: Thanks for info but let's I have 10000 files inside a directory and files are large some gbs so wholeTextFiles() will fail if I will use collect() ,  it won't be able to hold the content . How these files will be processed concurrently or separately.

Answer (score 0):

Spark can read files inside a directory in parallel.

For that you need to use `sc.wholeTextFiles`.

It will read a directory of text files from HDFS, a local file system (available on all nodes), or any Hadoop-supported file system URI. Each file is read as a single record and returned in a key-value pair, where the key is the path of each file, the value is the content of each file.

For example, if you have the following files:

```
hdfs://a-hdfs-path/file1.txt
hdfs://a-hdfs-path/file2.txt
...
hdfs://a-hdfs-path/fileN.txt
```

Do val rdd = sparkContext.wholeTextFile("hdfs://a-hdfs-path"),

then rdd contains

```
(a-hdfs-path/file1.txt, its content)
(a-hdfs-path/file2.txt, its content)
...
(a-hdfs-path/fileN.txt, its content)
```

**Note** - On some filesystems, `.../path/*` can be a more efficient way to read all files in a directory rather than `.../path/` or `.../path`. Small files are preferred, large file is also allowable, but may cause bad performance.

Comment: Yes bad performance or OOM issue. I have a question how all files will be processed concurrently or separately please let me know